# How to properly connect a QProgressBar with a QFutureWatcher?

Tags: qt

I want the progress of the function to be displayed on progressBar. Following the guides, I wrote the code below. But during the execution of the function, the program freezes, then progress bar's value becomes equal to one.

The program itself will not produce errors. The result of the function is correct.

I think my problem is that I don’t know how to connect the value of the progress of a function with the value of a progress bar.

(Form.h)

```
public:
    MyObject object;
    QFutureWatcher<QBitArray> FutureWatcher;
    QFuture<QBitArray> future;
```

(Form.cpp) Form constructor body:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
ui->progressBar->setMinimum(0);
ui->progressBar->setMaximum(100);
connect(&this->FutureWatcher, SIGNAL(progressValueChanged(int)), ui->progressBar, SLOT(setValue(int)));
```

(Form.cpp) Function on_button_clicked():

```
  void Form::on_button_clicked()
    {
        QString message = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
        future = QtConcurrent::run(&this->object, &MyObject::longFunction, message);
        this->FutureWatcher.setFuture(future);
        QBitArray bitresult = future.result();

    }
```

Comment: remove `QBitArray bitresult = future.result();`

Comment: Off-topic: You should consider using the new connect syntax:
`connect(&FutureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher::progressValueChanged, ui->progressBar, &QProgressBar::setValue);`
It has compile time checks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're immediately calling `future.result()`. The problem with this is that `result()` will wait until the `QFuture` has finished.

The Qt documentation says (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuture.html#result):

> If the result is not immediately available, this function will block and wait for the result to become available.

The solution is to connect a slot to `QFutureWatcher::finished()`:

```cpp
auto *watcher = new QFutureWatcher<QBitArray>(this);
connect(watcher, &QFutureWatcher::finished, this, [=]() {
    auto result = watcher->result();

    // do something with the result

    // important: delete watcher again
    watcher->deleteLater();
});

// now start the task
QString message = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
watcher->setFuture(QtConcurrent::run(myObject, &MyObject::longFunction, message));
```

Comment: With upcoming Qt 6, you could also use `future.then([]() {});`. That's a bit easier, but you'll need Qt 6 for it.

Comment: As he mentioned "I think my problem is that I don’t know how to connect the value of the progress of a function with the value of a progress bar." his problem is connecting the FutureWatcher's signal to his progressbar to indicate the progress. Not about reading the results. If he waits until the finish he cannot update the progress bar as the method execution going on.